# Condition check worksheet range python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a program that parses data from multiple workbook with multiple worksheets.

sheets 2 to 9 are days of the week(Sun-Sat). However some sheets have a different sheet range.

Some sheets have 2 to 5(Mon-Fri). Everything else is the same only some workbook have a total of 10 sheets while other have 8 sheets. My code will do the same parsing of cell range.

How can I still use my code to parse the workbooks that have a sheet range(2, 5)? This is what I have so far.

```
import glob
import openpyxl

path = 'C:/SomeFolder/*.xlsx'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
NameFile = file.rsplit('~', 2)[0]
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Title')
sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('TOTAL')
Week = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value
Date = sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value
Name = sheet.cell(row=4, column=2).value
Title = sheet.cell(row=5, column=2).value
Site = sheet.cell(row=6, column=2).value
LocID = sheet.cell(row=7, column=2).value
Total = sheet2.cell(row=26, column=2).value
if wb.worksheets is range(2, 9):
    for n in range(2, 9):
        sheets = wb.worksheets[n]
        Days = wb.sheetnames[n]
        comment = sheets.cell(row=34, column=5).value
        for i in range(2, 57):
            From = sheets.cell(row=i, column=1).value
            To = sheets.cell(row=i, column=2).value
            Activity = sheets.cell(row=i, column=3).value
            TimeSheet = {'Sender': NameFile, 'Week': Week, 'Date': Date, 'Name': Name, 'Title': Title, 'Site': Site, 'LocID': LocID,
                        'Days': Days, 'From': From, 'To': To, 'Activity': Activity, 'Week Total': Total, 'Comments': comment}
else:
    for n in range(2, 5):
        for n in range(2, 9):
            sheets = wb.worksheets[n]
            Days = wb.sheetnames[n]
            comment = sheets.cell(row=34, column=5).value
            for i in range(2, 57):
                From = sheets.cell(row=i, column=1).value
                To = sheets.cell(row=i, column=2).value
                Activity = sheets.cell(row=i, column=3).value
                TimeSheet = {'Sender': NameFile, 'Week': Week, 'Date': Date, 'Name': Name, 'Title': Title,
                             'Site': Site, 'LocID': LocID,
                             'Days': Days, 'From': From, 'To': To, 'Activity': Activity, 'Week Total': Total,
                             'Comments': comment}
print(TimeSheet)
```

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you break this code into functional units. At the moment it is almost impossible to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually iterate through the worksheets as follows:

```
for sheet in wb:
    if sheet.title=='Title':
        #Skip the title page with continue or do something to it here
        continue
    else:
        #for all pages other than the title page
        for i in range(2, 57):
             From = sheet.cell(i, column=1).value
             To= sheet.cell(i, column=2).value
```

Note how I skipped the Title sheet with an if statement. You could skip other specific sheets in this way.